# Remove APT repositories disabled after upgrade to 18.04

Tags: apt, upgrade, google-chrome

After upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 there are different APT repositories disabled.

I see this via app "Stacer".

I can't delete this, and I can't find this when I check in folder:

`ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d`

So I am not sure how to delete.

I found also from google chrome, even if I never installed it.. pretty strange?

Check this:

[image]
The other question suggest to remove from Softare center, but in 18.04 I can't find it. And from source.list directory, the disabled APT is not there.

Comment: I try to follow other questions, but:

Comment: 1. Software center can't find in new 18.04

Comment: 2. From sources.list.d is not there the disabled APT

Comment: Answer accepted, duplicate does not mention same.  **Voting to leave open**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Open *Software & Update* program already installed in Ubuntu.

- Use the Dash or Show Applications:

[image]

- Alternately open **Ubuntu Software** and then Menu > Software & Update
- Alternately open a terminal and enter `software-properties-gtk`

Go to the tab **Other Softeware**.

The Repositories that are **Uncheked** are disabled.

Then either **Edit...** to enable (Chrome, for example) or **Remove** (others you don't need).

## When you edit:

Some of the disabled repositories may have "xenial" in the text. You will need to replace "xenial" with "bionic" before you enable them so that they point to the right repository version.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. I don't find Software & Update. I open  Ubuntu Software and then I found in menu Software & Update...

Comment: But seem work.. However, very annoying to delete one by one..

Comment: the "unchecked" APT in other software, are this disabled?

Comment: Run `software-properties-gtk` for  Software & Update..

Comment: The link I mentioned as duplicate is quite dated - Do you want to take a crack at editing it?

Comment: @CharlesGreen Thanks! I have already made some updates to the old accepted answer. Let me know if they make sense and if you have any suggestions.

Comment: Looks good.  I probably should have created a chat to suggest this.

Comment: Thank You! One question... If I delete before rename "xenial" to "bionic", how to re-add this? (Yes I did that :(

Comment: Ask a new question. It depends on which entries you deleted and if you really need them in bionic.

Comment: I added here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1132362/which-apt-repositories-is-required-on-ubuntu-18-04