# Which APT repositories is required on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, package-management, repository

I have remove the disabled APT repositories, but as suggested here [Remove APT repositories disabled after upgrade to 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1132174/remove-apt-repositories-disabled-after-upgrade-to-18-04/1132185#1132185) I didn't do this:

"Some of the disabled repositories may have "xenial" in the text. You will need to replace "xenial" with "bionic" before you enable them so that they point to the right repository version."

Which APT I need to add, this is my current list of APT:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four main repository which you need to ensure you get the most of Ubuntu packages, it is.

> The "Ubuntu Software" tab displays a list of repositories or "Channels". The four main repositories are:
>
> ```
> Main - Canonical-supported free and open-source software.
>
> Universe - Community-maintained free and open-source software.
>
> Restricted - Proprietary drivers for devices.
>
> Multiverse - Software restricted by copyright or legal issues.
> ```
>
> For a detailed description of these repositories, see [Repositories](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories).

Considering you are upgraded from Xenial to Bionic, the repositories you own must have listed as `Xenial` version, you can simply all occurance of `Xenial` to `Bionic`.

```
sudo sed -i "s/xenial/bionic/g" /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt update
```

Also, creating a brand new source list may help. This will rename the old source list to `sources.list.bak` (in which you can return anytime), and create new `sources.list`—fill them with four main Bionic repository.

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.bak
echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted multiverse universe" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt update
```

Comment: Thank You Jim for quick and detailed report. As I understand I can just run the last commands that you posted. Means 1) Make backup of current sources.list and then 2) create a new one using the second command. Am I right? That would be the basic that I need?

Comment: Yeah, be aware that would remove 3rd party repositories. But you can anytime add it again, no big deal.

Comment: Thanks Jim, I think you mean Vivaldi and Stacer; I will add them after.. Will try now

Comment: I run the two command, and now I have just one line in sources.list, this: cat /etc/apt/sources.list 
"deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted multiverse universe"

Comment: It's this correct?

Comment: No that's not correct, there isn't supposed to be `cat` on the `sources.list`—please remove it immediately.

Comment: You have to paste `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted multiverse universe` on source list.

Comment: There is not "cat ..." I just copy/paste the command to see content of that file. This is the screenshot of APT list: https://ibb.co/SK4Hd5v

Comment: The content of sources.list is now:

Comment: deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted multiverse universe
deb https://repo.vivaldi.com/archive/deb/ stable main
# deb-src https://repo.vivaldi.com/archive/deb/ stable main

Comment: As you can see, I still see "xenial" entry in APT list of Software & Updates... Why?

Comment: I see that they are inside sources.list.d directory, can I delete this entries? Check https://ibb.co/JvZSwkL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92185/discussion-between-emmet-and-zoroaster).